# foreach object in array won't work while for loop working

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I have an php parameter of an XML feed I get using simplexml_load_file.
Here is the var_dump for some of my parameter so you will see the structure.

`object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "2.0" } ["channel"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (5) { ["title"]=> string(20) "BWM: CarolinaCooking" ["link"]=> string(69) "http://mybluewavemedia.com/portal/v2/feeds/ovg/45_CarolinaCooking.xml" ["description"]=> string(43) "Blue Wave Media Video MRSS Feed for OVGuide" ["lastBuildDate"]=> string(31) "Mon, 04 Nov 2013 09:10:44 +0000" ["item"]=> array(29) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (4) { ["title"]=> string(32) "Vanilla Cream with Fresh Berries" ["description"]=> string(135) "Host Thom Zelenka and Chef Catherine Rabb of Fenwick's on Providence restaurant teach you how to make Vanilla Cream with Fresh Berries." ["guid"]=> string(22) "BWM-CLIENT45-ITEM34340" ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Thu, 07 Feb 2013 05:43:12 +0000" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (4) { ["title"]=> string(33) "Meatloaf Stuffed with Blue Cheese" ["description"]=> string(153) "Host Thom Zelenka and Chef Catherine Rabb of Frenwick's on Providence restaruant teach you how to make Meatloaf Stuffed with Blue Cheese, Tomato & Bacon." ["guid"]=> string(22) "BWM-CLIENT45-ITEM34338" ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Thu, 07 Feb 2013 05:43:12 +0000" } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (4) { ["title"]=> string(23) "Creole Barbecued Shrimp" ["description"]=> string(127) "Host Thom Zelenka and Chef Catherine Rabb of Fenwick's on Provoidence restaurant teach you how to make Creole Barbecued shrimp." ["guid"]=> string(22) "BWM-CLIENT45-ITEM34336" ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Thu, 07 Feb 2013 05:43:12 +0000" } [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (4) { ["title"]=> string(23) "Caribbean Banana Foster" ["description"]=> string(156) "Host Thom Zelenka and Chef Mathew Beard of the Speedway Club restaurant teach you how to make a Caribbean Bananas Foster with Toasted Coconut-Rum Ice Cream." ["guid"]=> string(22) "BWM-CLIENT45-ITEM34334" ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Thu, 07 Feb 2013 05:43:12 +0000" } [4]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (4) { ["title"]=> string(19) "Seared Veal Cutlets" ["description"]=> string(155) "Host Thom Zelenka and Chef Mathew Beard of the Speedway Culb restaurant teach you how to make Seared Veal Cutlets with Pan Roasted Lobster and Potato Hash." ["guid"]=> string(22) "BWM-CLIENT45-ITEM34332" ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Thu, 07 Feb 2013 05:43:12 +0000" }`

As you can see there is an array named "item".
What I simply tried to do is create an foreach loop that echo's the title of each object in "item" array.
I did this as following:

```
foreach($videos->channel->item as $video);
        {
        var_dump($video);
        echo "<BR><BR>";
        echo "TITLE: " . $video->title . "<BR>";
        }
```

This simply didn't work. It only printed the last title in the array.

The strange thing is that when I created an loop this way, it did work:

```
$i=0;
    while($i<30) {
    echo $i . $videos->channel->item[$i]->title . "<BR>";
    $i++;
    }
```

Could anyone try and explain me why it won't work through foreach loop?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should work

```
$i=0;
foreach($videos->channel->item as $video) {
echo "TITLE: " . $video[$i]->title;
$i++;
}
```

**EDIT (Other way):**

```
foreach($videos->channel->item as $video) {
    foreach($video as $val)
     {
        echo "TITLE: " . $val->title;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Works!!!This is very strange... Could you please explain to me why it does work this way?

Comment: Às you can see, $video is also an array. But you had accessed it as a variable, that's why you didn't get the results.

Comment: you put a semi clone(;) in foreach. Use `foreach($videos->channel->item as $video)` instead of `foreach($videos->channel->item as $video);`

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain, Nope that was not the issue.

Comment: Ohh. of course. but why do you add the $i for the $video? Doesn't it need to be $video->title only?

Comment: definitely your issue is main issue. is this worked `foreach($videos->channel->item as $video);`

Comment: Nope nimi how would that be possible ? If you access that way you will only get the last element that was accessed on your for loop. As you know it is an array and it has its own levels. Try the other answer too.

Comment: Ok... Of course after removing the ; it works fine. The strange thing that I dont understand is that it works both for $video[$i] and $video. I don't really understand why $video[$i] works.

Comment: Why not ? As i said $video is an array. The second example would help you understand very much better [*i guess*].

Comment: It will probably help to stop thinking of SimpleXMLElement objects as arrays: they can be used as though they were arrays, but also as though they were "normal" objects. You cannot understand their behaviour by comparing them to other parts of PHP, because they have a lot of "magic"...

Comment: The semi-colon is the main issue, and should be added as an answer: it causes the foreach loop to contain zero statements, so it loops all the way through and leaves $video set to the last element of the loop when the echo is executed. The alternatives here are misleading.